# How can I handle onListItemClick(...) based on what view inside the row was clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

**Question**

I have a listView inside a DialogFragment and I want to fire certain callbacks only when certain particular items inside a row are fired. How can I do that?

Basically, I want to do something like this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final int viewId = view.getId();
    if ((viewId == R.id.textView1) || (viewId == R.id.textView2)) {
        // do something...
    }
```

which I can't. Read further if you don't know why.

**What I tried**

I tried to look into the documentation, but the OnItemClickListener callback doesn't offer as a parameter the exact clicked view (the View you can see in the signature is the whole row).

Also, I tried to set a simple onClick callback on the single view in the adapter, but this overrides the listSelector and other behavior a list should have. Reading in the documentation, I found it's explicitly written that we should set callbacks via the onListItemClick(...) method (not via onClick(...)), so I'm looking for a way to do that, using this method, not to override any default list behavior.

I was trying to get this done by working on the xml. To my surprise, I found that if I set a view `android:clickable` property to true, the onListItemClick callback won't fire (I thought it was the opposite),
so a partial solution would be to set to `android:clickable=true` every view in the row apart from the one I want to fire the callback, but that is not a solution because if the user clicks where there is padding or white space, the callback will fire. Also, I found that if I set the parent of the row's view to `android:clickable=true` and the child views I want to handle with the callback to `android:clickable=false`, this won't work, because apparently the property is not overwritten.

**EDIT** Sorry for the really bad title this question had before, I didn't even noticed I submitted the question.

Answer (score 0):

new Answer, hope I understood now :)

In your adapters getView, attach an OnClickListener to any view in your layout you want to fire. (more pseudocode)

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<XYZ> {

    private int resource;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null) convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(this.resource, parent, false);

        ((Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_IN_LAYOUT)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DOSTUFF();
            }
        });

        return convertView ;
    }


}
```

old Answer:
The position indicates where you are in the list (pseudocode).

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position,long arg3) {

        YOUR_ITEM_BACKED_BY_ADAPTER item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

        if(item==THE_FIRST_ITEM_IN_LIST) doSomething();
        else if(item == THE_LAST_ITEM_IN_LIST) doSomethingElse();               
    }

});
```

Comment: you may want to read my edit, as maybe the previous title led you out of way, figuring out witch listItem was clicked is not my problem. I have to figure out which View inside of a listItem, was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set listeners for other views inside the adapter's getView

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> implements View.OnClickListener  {
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // setup the converView inflating it, for simplicity I've removed that code

        MyItem item = getItem(position);
        text1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text1.setOnClickListener(this);
        // pass the item to use when clicked
        text1.setTag(item);

        text2.setOnClickListener(this);
        text2.setTag(item);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyItem item = v.getTag();

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.text1:
                download(item);
                break;
            case R.id.text2:
                upload(item);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of hardcoding action (eg `download`) inside the adapter you can pass to it an interface and for example the calling activity can implement that interface

Comment: This is the second paragraph of 'what i tried'. Sorry if it's not clear. I'll try to re-explain why this isn't a solution here. If I do this, the list item won't be in the selected state when I click it e.g. the whole list row won't highlight, because you're using a simple onClick function, while you're expected to use the OnListItemClick. This last function apart from executing the callback you specify, takes care of checking that the listItem behaves as so, not as a simple view. I appreciate you taking your time to answer though, so thank you :)