# Android access EditText in Listview button

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way to update edittext in listview other then creating a customadapter?
In my listview there is an edittext and button. I want to update edittext text on button.click event.
I couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: I suppose you have already created a custom Adapter when you added a button and edittext on your listview. Why are you asking about creating a custom Adapter?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say you can't find a way to do it, when you already have found the way to do it. As it seems you just don't want to do it... create a custom adapter.

Have a look here, it explains how to do it with a custom adapter.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024425/2001247